# beautifulsoup to retrieve the date

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to retrieve the date from the product page: `http://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-41-in-16-Drawer-Tool-Chest-and-Cabinet-Set-HOTC4016B1QES/205080371`

But the date is hidden in the meta information,see first line:

```
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2014-11-27" />
</div><div id='80886327' itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"><meta itemprop="itemReviewed" content="HUSKY 41 in. 16-Drawer Tool Chest and Cabinet Set" /><span itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">Rated <span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span> out of <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span></span>Â by <span itemprop="author">Razor</span><span itemprop="name"> solid construction
</span><span itemprop="description"> I spent the last month checking and looking at all tool boxes that I could find. Online and at available stores. In comparison to all, this is by far the best deal for the money. Quality, workmanship and construction of this is by far the best for the money. Some I looked at are twice as much money for the same quality... I have had this approx. a month and filled with tools and shop stuff and with the ball bearing drawers loaded, does not make any difference on drawer operation. Granted we still need the test of time..
```

Do you guys know how to save these dates into a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) to get all the `meta` tags with `itemprop="datePublished"`:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-41-in-16-Drawer-Tool-Chest-and-Cabinet-Set-HOTC4016B1QES/205080371'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url=url))

print [meta.get('content') for meta in soup.find_all('meta', itemprop='datePublished')]
```

Prints:

```
[
    '2014-11-27', 
    '2014-11-20', 
    '2014-12-15', 
    '2014-10-28', 
    '2014-10-10'
]
```

Or, with a [`CSS Selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
print [meta.get('content') for meta in soup.select('meta[itemprop="datePublished"]')]
```